# Debugging Custom QuickLook Plugin with Breakpoints

Tags: xcode, quicklook

I'm having trouble getting my custom QuickLook Plugin to stop on my breakpoints.

I've tried several approaches with different schemes.

In Post-actions, I've added this in the Run Script:

```
rm -Rf "~/Library/QuickLook/$FULL_PRODUCT_NAME"
cp -R "$(BUILD_DIR)/Debug/CustomQuickLookPlug-In.qlgenerator" ~/Library/QuickLook
qlmanage -r
```

I've also tried the approach mentioned in [Debugging Quicklook Plugin in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811547/debugging-quicklook-plugin-in-xcode-4-6).

I get an error saying com.apple.CFPasteboardClient; this is likely due to sandbox restrictions  Is there any way to bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you need to copy and paste the qlmanager executable to another location and have your schema run that copy instead to bypass the security just to debug your QuickLook plugin.