# How to debug quicklook plugin on macOS Catalina?

Tags: plugins, macos-catalina, quicklook

I have a `quicklook` plugin which generates Finder thumbnails and QuickLook Previews for my custom file extension for files in my Virtual File System (developed via `FUSE`).

The problem is that on macOS Catalina, QuickLook Preview doesn't work for files with specified extension.
Usually, I debug this by having `GenerateThumbnailForURL.m` '`echo`' debug text to a file on Desktop OR `NSLog` or `os_log` so that content is visible in `Console.app`.

However, when `Console.app` displays the log text from my plugin, it is shrouded with `<private>` items instead of actual content.

Is there a way to circumvent this for `Console.app` or some other way in which `QuickLook plugin` can be debugged on macOS Catalina?

I tried [this](https://saagarjha.com/blog/2019/09/29/making-os-log-public-on-macos-catalina/#putting-it-all-together) but it doesn't seem to work on macOS Catalina 10.15.3.

Comment: I successfully followed the debugging steps from [Debugging Quicklook Plugin in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811547/debugging-quicklook-plugin-in-xcode) in macOS Monterey 12.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `GeneratePreviewForURL` for quicklook preview generation on Catalina.

Instead, one should implement the `QuickLook Preview Extension` target. Launching the target will open the debug session where everything can be debbuged in classical way.

Btw, echo-ing from `GenerateThumbnailForURL.m` should no longer work on Catalina because the extension doesn't have write permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can still debug Quick Look Plugins on macOS Catalina.
I am on 10.15.6 and using the following:

- Add NSLog(...) statements to your code.
- Build your .qlgenerator file and install it into ~/Library/QuickLook
- run `qlmanage -r` to activate your new plugin
- run `qlmanage -p someFile` to run the preview generation and see the NSLog statements of GeneratePreviewForURL in the Terminal.
- run `qlmanage -t someFile` to run the icon generation and see the NSLog statements of GenerateThumbnailForURL in the Terminal.

Comment: Correct, QuickLook Plugin debugging works in macOS Catalina or even macOS Monterey. For improved debugging experience, there is a dedicated question: [Debugging Quicklook Plugin in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811547/debugging-quicklook-plugin-in-xcode)